# Sort my display by occurrence in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

The principle is to sort in ascending order to display first the names that have the most common city:

```
enter code here
```

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `name`, `firstname`, `City`) VALUES
(1, 'Salomon', 'Farouk', 'Marseille'),
(2, 'Sangronio', 'Frederic', 'Paris'),
(3, 'Soulé', 'Faiza', 'New York'),
(4, 'Massimo', 'Franck', 'Marseille');
```

I would like to display like this

```
(1, 'Salomon', 'Farouk', 'Marseille'),
(4, 'Massimo', 'Franck', 'Marseille');
(2, 'Sangronio', 'Frederic', 'Paris'),
(3, 'Soulé', 'Faiza', 'New York'),
```

et voila ma raquette mais ça ne marche pas

```
SELECT a.* FROM test a INNER JOIN
    (SELECT id,name,firstname,city, COUNT(*) as compte
     FROM test
     GROUP BY city
     ) AS c
     ON a.id = c.id
     ORDER BY compte DESC
```

Merci pour votre aide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current approach is on the right track, except that you are trying to join the subquery which finds the city counts to the main table using the `id`.  This doesn't even make sense for that subquery, which just finds cities and their counts.  Instead, join on the city name to a subquery which finds the city counts, and then use those counts for ordering the result set:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.compte
FROM test t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT city, COUNT(*) AS compte
    FROM test
    GROUP BY city
) t2
    ON t1.city = t2.city
ORDER BY t2.compte DESC
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester